# How can I trigger a script when local jekyll file changes?

Tags: jekyll

I am running a jekyll server for a local site with `bundle exec jekyll serve`. When I make edits to a file in the site, jekyll regenerates the files automatically. I'd also like a script I have to be triggered to automatically to refresh my browser. How can I trigger this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short words, run Jekyll with the `--livereload` parameter.
The command will look like this:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload
```

For more information, call help command:

```
jekyll help serve
```

Here are the parameters that may be useful:

```
-l, --livereload   Use LiveReload to automatically refresh browsers
    --livereload-ignore ignore GLOB1[,GLOB2[,...]]  Files for LiveReload to ignore. Remember to quote the values so your shell won't expand them
    --livereload-min-delay [SECONDS]  Minimum reload delay
    --livereload-max-delay [SECONDS]  Maximum reload delay
    --livereload-port [PORT]  Port for LiveReload to listen on
```

You can of course combine options.

For example:
To run second project with Jekyll at the same time you need to set other port and another port for LiveReload.

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload --livereload-port 8080 --port 4001
```

And now in your browser you can see the second project at http://localhost:4001/ or http://0.0.0.0:4001/

Comment: So in other words, I don't need to implement my own script at all. There's an option for it already built into the command. Very simple. I just tried it and it works great!

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to run two different sites on different ports locally and still use --livereload? I seem to be running into an issue when I try. I get an error from eventmachone.rb:351:  `'start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)`